# Drupal 7 Login code files?

Tags: drupal, authentication, drupal-7, customization

Hi i'm just new to Drupal and trying to modify the drupal login for some customizations. So far the Drupal structure is complicated for me yet, I'm just needing to know:

- What are the main files for Login procedure?

Is it possible to customize the login like that, without going with new `module` creating way?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you mean by customization. If you want to change the look and feel of the page, you can do so with some custom theming. http://drupal.org/documentation/theme

If you want to do common things like allowing people to log in using OpenID then there's usually an existing 3rd party module for that which you could find by Googling what you need.

But if you want to do something more customized than that then you're probably going to need to create a custom module, and use [hook_form_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) and the [Form API](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7) to add/customize fields, add custom validation or submit handlers, stuff like that.